# Spring MVC: two identical forms on page using one bean, same parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So I have a page with layout:

```
<form:form id='form1'>
<form:hidden path="order" />

<form:form id='form2'>
<form:hidden path="order" />
```

Constructor:

```
public ModelAndView showListView(Model model,
    @ModelAttribute("form1") FormSearch form1,
    @ModelAttribute("form2") FormSearch form2){
```

When I press button on form1 to receive 'order' value, I see that browser sends values correctly form1:order is newValue and form2:order is oldValue. But in constructor I receive form1:order newValue and form2:order newValue. So I think Spring is searching for first param value for both forms, which is incorrect.

What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from different thread fixed the issue:

```
@InitBinder("form2")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<form:form id='form1' modelAttribute="form1">
<form:form id='form2' modelAttribute="form2">
```

Comment: @MarkM. have you tried `model.addAttribute('form1', form1)` and `model.addAttribute('form2', form2)`

Comment: Didn't help, but thank you anyway. Answer from different thread saved the day!